# Mysql delete with join not working

Tags: mysql

I want to delete orphan records from my table, I have user and accounts table and a user account mapping table.
When I execute the below-given query it shows syntax error, please help.

```
delete from user_accounts  where user_accounts.user_id not in(select user_id from user_accounts ua inner join  user u on ua.user_id= u.id);
```

The error I got:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'user_accounts' for update in FROM clause

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: What is the error? could you please post it as well.

Comment: Hi error updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `left join`

```
delete ua 
from user_accounts ua
left join user u on ua.user_id = u.id
where u.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`User` is the [reserved keyword here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), escape the keyword around with **`**

So your query will be:

```
delete uac
from user_accounts uac
where uac.`user_id` not in
(select `user_id` from user_accounts ua inner join `user` u on ua.`user_id` = u.id);
```

Comment: `user` is a keyword, but it is not reserved.